# List View can't be seen, Nothing is rendered on screen

Tags: android, listview

I have a List view Which should be populated with Data from a array list,

Heres the code:

```
public class List_view extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        ListView Trainlist;
        Trainlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.station_list);
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        try{
            Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select Station_name From Station", null);

            String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
            int i= 0;
            while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
                String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
                station_array[i] = name;
                Log.d("STATION_GET!","Retrieved station " + station_array[i]);
                //Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Retrieved station " + station_array[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                throwlist.add(name);
                i++;

            }
            data_fetch.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "An Error occured Retrieving your data" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,throwlist);
            Trainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error in listview ",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

When i Run the app Nothing comes up in the activity here is the XMl data of the list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/station_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
```

And yes Ive Confirmed that the data bse in question does indeed have some data it.
This is the logcat output of the data retrieved from the database

```
    10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station New York
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Boston
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Las Vegas
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Miami
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Chicago
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station New England
10-29 06:55:57.721 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Detroit
10-29 06:55:57.722 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Michigan
10-29 06:55:57.722 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station Austin
10-29 06:55:57.722 31050-31050/com.example.arun.db D/STATION_GET!: Retrieved station New Orleans
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: setContentView wrong positioning, written twice?

Comment: Where Should the setContent() be?

Comment: I was Following the instructions on [here] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm) @cyborg91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove second **setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);**. Why you calling multiple TIME ?
- Before writing code, Think. You should read [**`official Tutorials`**](http://developer.android.com).

**Don't**

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
            ListView Trainlist;
```

**Do**

```
ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView Trainlist;  
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
```

Comment: The Second instance of setcontent() was there by error didnt mean to put that there

Comment: @ArunMani after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @ArunMani Read my answer carefully. `setContentView` call one time

Comment: Thank You the error was the second 'setContentview' I accidentally called it multiple times Thank You Very much